# ASIHTTPRequest-multiple request

Tags: iphone, facebook, asihttprequest

I am developing an app that will request the profile picture URL of some users from Facebook servers, but I don't know how many users I will have (it might be 2 or it might be 20). Should I use `ASIHTTPRequest` with a loop and a synchronous request, or the API graph (with Facebook SDK for iOS) with a loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying using ASINetworkQueue. It will allow you to create a queue of ASIHTTPRequests that can still be started asynchronously. For example

```
- (void)getImages
{
    if(!self.queue)
        self.queue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSArray* urlStringsToRequest = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.example.com/image1.png",@"http://www.example.com/image2.png",nil];
    for(NSString* urlString in urlStringsToRequest)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
        [self.queue addOperation:request];
    }

    [self.queue go];
}

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest*)req
{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[req responseData]];

    [imageArray addObject:image];
}

- (void)requestWentWrong:(ASIHTTPRequest*)req
{
    NSLog(@"Request returned an error %@",[req error]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I want the results to present them. Can i use didfinish with asinetwork queue?

Comment: Indeed, see https://gist.github.com/150447 for a simplistic (but complete) example.

Comment: You can either put a didFinishSelector on the queue or each individual request. Either works. I updated the answer with how you would get the image out of the request.

Comment: ok last question :P what these lines doing? if(!self.queue)
        self.queue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease]; and     for(NSString* urlString in urlStringsToRequest). and how I manage the requests?

Comment: The if(!self.queue line checks to see if a queue has been created already and doesn't re-create it if it already exists. The for loop uses fast enumeration to loop through every url in that array and create a request for it.